# How to properly deal with a Java VM crash report

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-crash

I run a game server made with Java directly on the Eclipse (in debug mode), and each 24 hours more or less it just crash.

It drops me a crash report log and an error on the Eclipse Console, and I would like to know what I can do to trace the problem because right now everything I have is just this log and I dont know at all where to look to solve the issue.

I have to say that it doesn't happens with previous versions of Java (7), it started with the Java version 8.

I've been stuck on Java 7 till now because of this problem and now I would like to upgrade to use the new Java 8 features.

I would thank if someone can point me on the right direction to solve this issue.

Here is the log file:
Eclipse Console Error: http://pastebin.com/WGwpYdSW

Log Crash Dump: http://pastebin.com/zqFcVmpF

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any JNI code in your game?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jim but no, I dont have any JNI code.

Comment: sounds like a jvm bug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jim, I'll report it to Oracle and see If I can finally use Java 8 on my life :).

Comment: The crash happened in JVM thread that was coordinating garbage collection operation. I noticed from the crash log that minidump was written. It could be helpful for investigation if you could ever share it (though minidump may contain sensitive information).

Comment: Thanks for your answer apangin, there is a 7GB dump called hs_err_pid4864.mdmp, but inside looks like a some sort of HEX information (numbers, letters, symbols..), could it be used for something?

I opened it with Ultra Edit.

Comment: @Dr.House after inspecting your log, I am unable to figure out what has caused the issue, as neither there is stacktrace not any problematic frame information. Core-dump file is generated on release build. If you have core-dump generated on fastdebug build, it makes sense

Comment: Thanks for answer Fairoz, this means that running it in release instead of debug I could get more information about the issue at the "next" crash? If is the case I worth to try!

Comment: Even though .mdmp looks weird, with some debugging skills it can be useful for reconstruction of Java heap, thread stacks, internal VM structures etc. as they were at the moment of crash. The outcome is not guaranteed but it may worth a try.

Comment: @Dr.House here is the instructions to create and deploy fastdebug builds - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html. once generated core dump file you can mail to me. Thanks